# json input parameter in remix.ethereum

Tags: remix

How can i trigger smart contract function with giving json data to a parameter that accepts string on remix.ethereum ide?

I tried [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70954/how-to-handle-json-in-a-smart-contract?rq=1) answer but didnt work.

My contract is here

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Json {
    function getParameter(string memory jsonData) public view returns (string memory) {
        return jsonData;
    }
}
```

I tried this as image shows and got error

[image]
[image]

```
call to Json.getParameter errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":3}, value={"types":["string"],"values":["{ \\",":\\","}"]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.3.1)
```

Those ones dont work either

```
{ "name":"John"}

{ name:John}
```

Does anybody help me?